# Do I need to trim my SSD? How?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, trim

I have been using a pair of Intel 320 in RAID 1 on my busy Ubuntu server for about 4 month. While the disk usage never reached 50% of the capacity, but I FEEL that the server has become less responsive, so I'm wondering whether I need to run a trim, an if yes, how to do so? (The Linux kernel is 3.0 after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10)

Thanks

Comment: You... feel it... just what unit of measurement is that?

Comment: I wrote feel in capital just to indicate that I have no objective measure to support the claim. It is just my feeling :)

Comment: Until you can support your feeling with actual statistics, we can't help you.  I'm sorry to break it to you, but servers don't have feelings.